# Как проверить был ли зарегистрирован пользователь?

Tags: php, laravel, email, регистрация, laravel5.4

При регистрации нового пользователя (login, email, password) необходимо проверить, а нет ли уже юзера с такой почтой. Если нет - регистрируем, если есть - выводим сообщение "Пользователь с таким email уже был зарегистрирован". Подскажите пожалуйста, как такое реализовать?

Пытаюсь вывести ошибку так:

```
            @if ($errors->any())
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <strong>Ошибка!</strong> {{ $error }}
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @endif
```

Comment: Проверять наличие имейла среди имейлов зарегистрированных пользователей.

Comment: Это и так понятно. А по-конкретнее? Может быть есть какие-то встроенные методы проверки? Делаю вот так: $checkEmail = User::where('email', '=', $email)->count(); но это проблемы не решает..

Comment: Какой именно проблемы не решает? В чем выражается "нерешение" проблемы?

Comment: @YuriGo, Вы даже можете сделать проверку при валидации данных, т.е. : `email' => 'required|unique:users'`, и тогда валидация не пройдёт, если почта уже есть.

Comment: @entithat, а можно вас попросить решение целиком?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, к примеру.
В методе регистрации пользователя написать следующее:

```
public function createUser(Request $request) 
{
    $messages = [
        'email.unique' => 'Пользователь уже существует'
    ];

    Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email'    => 'required|unique:users|max:255'
        // Тут валидация других полей
    ], $messages)->validate();

    // А тут остальная логика
}
```

Тогда если почта уже будет занята, то сработает автоматический редирект с ошибкой, указанной в массиве `$messages`.

---

P.S. Но если Вы использовали стандартную авторизацию `php artisan make:auth`, то в контроллере `Auth/RegisterController.php` измените так же метод `validator()`:

```
/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $messages = [
        'email.unique' => 'Пользователь уже существует'
    ];

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ], $messages);
}
```

Таким образом, мы добавили кастомное поле для почты.

**UPD**

Чтобы вывести все ошибки в представлении:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Благодарю! Да, я использовал стандартную авторизацию. Т.о. если мне нужно проверить только одно поле (email), то вместо $request->all() я должен добавить $email?

Comment: Можете оставить все поля, просто делать проверку для `email`.

Comment: Спасибо) И, я надеюсь, последний вопрос) Как собственно перехватить ошибку во вьюшке?)

Comment: Вываливается ошибка: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::make()

Comment: Верно, ведь надо добавить `use Validator;`

Comment: use Illuminate\Validation\Validator; - у меня уже добавлено. При попытке использовать use Validator; - подчеркивает

Comment: Ничего что подчеркивает, просто оставьте use Validator. Должно так тоже работать:) Ведь даже на официальном сайте пишут его использовать - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation

Comment: Ошибка ушла) При попытке добавить пользователя с одинаковым email, запись не добавляется в таблицу users, но и ошибка во вьюхе не отображает..

Comment: Странно, можете показать как выводите ошибку и что изменяли?

Comment: Дополнил в вопросе. А может быть такое, что вывод ошибок запрещен настройками фреймворка?

Comment: @YuriGo, нет, навряд. Сейчас подумаю, что не так. Попробуйте вывести просто `{{ dd($errors->all()) }}`, просто чтобы посмотреть есть ли в общем хоть что-то.

Comment: Выводит: array:1 [▼
  0 => "Пользователь уже существует"
]

Comment: Все работает, спасибо)

Comment: Не за что:) Всегда пожалуйста:).